# Find the min value in a range within a range in R

Tags: r, dataframe

i have a data frame that contains lap times of the same race for the last 10 years (1 race a year from 2007 to 2017) i am trying to extract the fastest time of each race from each year. i thought that using `min()` would do the trick but it does not as it finds the smallest values within all the lap times from all the years. here is the code:

`FL2007 = subset(AusLapTimes, AusLapTimes$Time.Seconds == min(AusLapTimes$Time.Seconds)  & AusLapTimes$year == 2007)`

2007 happens to be the year where the fastest lap of all time within the range occured so i do get data within the FL2007 DF but when i ran this:

`FL2008 = subset(AusLapTimes, AusLapTimes$Time.Seconds == min(AusLapTimes$Time.Seconds)  & AusLapTimes$year == 2008)`

`FL2009 = subset(AusLapTimes, AusLapTimes$Time.Seconds == min(AusLapTimes$Time.Seconds)  & AusLapTimes$year == 2009)`

the 2 extra DFs get created but with no values to display as the fasest ever lap was in 2007.

help please!

Comment: Take your favorite method from the "mean by group" R-FAQ, and replace `mean` with `min`.

Comment: For example, with `library(dplyr)`: `AusLapTimes %>% group_by(year) %>% summarize(min_time = min(Time.Seconds))`, or in base R: `aggregate(Time.Seconds ~ year, AusLapTimes, min)`.

Comment: @Gregor thanks for the answer mate. i did not look properly in SO hence it ended up being a duplicate!